# Using \email in the body of a cv

Tags: moderncv, cv

I am writing my CV using class `moderncv` and `classic` style.

When I am writing the contact details of my references, e.g email address, is there anyway the email address can be clicked like the the `\email` I used for my own email address.

Answer (score 1):

You gave no MWE so I have a little bit to guess.

I think you missunderstood that command `\email` is only used for your own email address.  If you want to add the email of another person just use command `\href{mailto:max.musterman@email.de}{max.musterman@email.de}`. It links to the valid link `mailto:max.musterman@email.de`, but shows printed only `max.musterman@email.de`.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org} % <======================================
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{References}
\cvlistitem{Max Mustermann, 
  \href{mailto:max.musterman@email.de}{max.musterman@email.de}} % <==================
\cvlistitem{Eva Musterfrau, 
  \href{mailto:eva.musterfrau@email.de}{eva.musterfrau@email.de}} % <=================

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]